# Vista: change clock tooltip to short date?

Tags: windows-vista, date, clock

Is it possible to change the tooltip that shows above the clock from the "Long date" format to show the "Short date" format?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is tho change the Long Date Format system-wide (!) in the Control Panel:

1. Open the Control Panel (Classic View)
2. Click on the Regional and Language Options icon.
3. Click on the Customize this format button.
4. Click on the Date tab.
5. Click on the drop down arrow to the right of the Long date: and click on the date format you want.
6. Click on the Apply button.

[Here are some other options](http://www.brightrev.com/how-to/windows/7-show-the-date-in-your-windows-vista-system-tray.html).

Comment: That doesn't work. All of the "long date" options say something like "19 July 2009" I want one that says "19/7/09" and there's no such options in the long dates combo.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I think there is no other option. At least the two other formats are shorter...

Answer (score -1):

Unless you particularly want to use the Vista built-in tray clock, you could try some of the [free tray clock replacements](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-tray-clock-replacement.htm) that are around and see if any of them suit you better.